# if statement problem while converting a vector

Tags: vhdl

im new at vhdl coding, and there is a problem with if statement

so my code is the following
i want to convert a vector(bar), if the statement is true (so in this example if its smaller than 10)

```
process(bar)
      variable tmp : integer;
    begin
      tmp := to_integer(signed(bar));
      if tmp < 10 then
            good(3) <= bar(3);
            good(2) <= bar(3) xor bar(2);
            good(1) <= bar(2) xor bar(1);
            good(0) <= bar(1) xor bar(0);
      end if;
    end process;
```

but the problem is that the statement is not working, if i put a bigger number for example "1111" it is converting in the same way as it converted before

Comment: Looks fine to me. What does your simulation tool say?

Comment: @Darhuuk idk if i test in the right way, but if i try to test theese values, then after 1001 i got values and not null
bar1: process
   begin        
        bar<= "0000";  wait for 50 ns;
        bar<= "0001";  wait for 50 ns;      
        bar<= "1010";  wait for 50 ns;
        bar<= "1100";  wait for 50 ns;
            
      wait;
   end process;

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you're testing, but not that the `good` signal will just keep it's previously value. So whenever `bar > 10`, the `good` signal will stop changing. It's not going to automatically reset itself to 0.

Comment: @Darhuuk is there some way to say if -> else than good will be null?

Comment: You dont show the vector of bar. From you text you say you set it to "1111", which is -1 (because of signed conversion). If `bar` is only 4 bits, then `tmp` is always less than 10 because 4 bit signed goes from -8 to +7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems you want `good` to be set to 0 whenever `bar >= 10`. In that case you can just do:

```
process(bar)
  variable tmp : integer;
begin
  tmp := to_integer(signed(bar));
  if tmp < 10 then
    good(3) <= bar(3);
    good(2) <= bar(3) xor bar(2);
    good(1) <= bar(2) xor bar(1);
    good(0) <= bar(1) xor bar(0);
  else
    good <= (others => '0');
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: An alternative is to place `good <= (others => '0');` before the IF. Then the default value (0) is overridden whenever the IF condition is met. Both ways work, and both have their uses in more complex designs.

Comment: @BrianDrummond True. I prefered the `else` here, since it makes it very explicit which of two things would happen.

Comment: It does make it explicit, and explicit is good. But there are cases where 1 default assignment saves 10 Else clauses, and simplicity is also good...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Definitely true :)!

Comment: @Darhuuk can i set something like 'undefined' for the else cases?

Comment: @mynemisnttom Sure, assuming `good` is an `std_logic_vector`, you can do `good <= (others => 'X');`. This has the added benefit that X'es propagate all through your design if you use them, so you'll immediately see if you're using the `good` signal as input when you're not supposed to (i.e. when it's `X`).

Answer (score 0):

The vector good is only assigned when tmp < 10. So there is a latch inferred by this process.
You need to define what's the "else" value for good in any other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You state that

> if i put a bigger number for example "1111" it is converting in the
> same way as it converted before

As Tricky pointed out in a comment above, your problem is this line here:

```
  tmp := to_integer(signed(bar));
                    ^^^^^^
```

You have not posted an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so I cannot be sure, but your question implies that `bar` is 4 bits wide. Assuming that is the case, the value `"1111"` as a `signed` number is -1. So, if `bar` is set to `"1111"`, `tmp` will be -1. -1 is less than 10, so this `if` statement will evaluate as `true`:

```
  if tmp < 10 then
```

If you consider than `"1111"` is greater than 10 (ie it's 15), then you need to convert via the `unsigned` type, ie

```
  tmp := to_integer(unsigned(bar));
                    ^^^^^^^^
```

The range of a 4-bit `signed` number is -8 to +7. All the values in that range are less than 10, so your `if` statement will evaluate as `true` whatever the value of `bar`.

The above solution assumes that `bar` is always zero or positive. If that is not the case, then you need more bits in the signal `bar`. 5 is enough. A 5-bit `signed` number has the range -16 to +15.

So, I can see two solutions:

1. use an `unsigned` type in your type conversion or
2. make `bar` 5 bits
   or wider.

---

Others have pointed out that, *assuming* this is synthsisable code and *assuming* that this is intended to be combinational logic, then you are missing a branch in your `if` statement; you don't drive the signal `good` in the case that the `if` statement is `false` and so if you were to synthesise this code as combinational logic, then you would get latches. But that is not the question you asked.

Comment: can i set something like 'undefined' for the else cases?

Comment: @mynemisnttom Yes. You can say `else good <= (others => '-');` assuming `good` is a `std_logic_vector` or a _closely related type_. `'-'` means _don't care_. (`'X'` doesn't really mean _don't care_, it means _unknown_ which isn't quite the same thing.)